# Reusing Knockout.js ViewModels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi there i'm building multipage application with Knockout.js and i'm facing a problem writing too much duplicated code..

As example in one of my views i have:

```
var personVm = function {

   //properties here

}

personVm.prototype {

  //extensions & methods here

}
```

And at some point i have to use the same ViewModel in some other view.. So i end up duplicating code..

I searched for solutions and require.js is the most common.. But in my case require.js is not suitable and i can't use it. So i will be glad if some one shares some ways to deal with this problem.

Update:

To clear more my question i need some kind of container from which i can grab instances of given ViewModel for my differen views ( which i get from asp.net )

Answer (score 1):

You could use knockouts own [`ko.utils.extend`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

```
var personVm = function {
   //properties here
}

personVm.prototype {
  //extensions & methods here
}
```

then, later

```
var superHeroVm = function() { 
    var self = this;

    self.specialPower = ko.observable();

    ko.utils.extend(self, new personVm());
}
```

Comment: Yes looks reasonable but i don't want to extend i just want to reuse the same ViewModel in different views.Plus how the ko.utils.extend(self, new personVM()) will be aware of personVM since personVM is in different script.Thanks

Comment: That's essentially what extend is doing. It's making 'personVm' a kind of 'base' for your other view model. so superHeroVm will contain personVm's properties

Comment: ... if you could flesh out your question to include more of what you are trying to achieve, i'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just keep personVm in a file which you can access from all over and make a new one each time?

```
thisModel.person = new personVm(data);

otherModel.person = new personVm(data);
```

Or am I not understanding the problem correctly?